# extra data between html tags using scrapy (not xpath)

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy spider and I want the user to be able to supply an html tag like `<span class="someclass"></span>` or `<a style="somestuff"></a>` and then use these tags to extract the text in betwen and put that in my results.
I really don't want the user to have to supply Xpath. I understand it may be easier to code with xpath but I will make my spider available to users who are not so tech savvy.

How would you do that?

Comment: If you want a user-friendly scraper, look at [Scrapely](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapely).

Comment: Not for Python, but my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) has a similar idea.  You can give it `<span class="someclass">{.}</span>*` as template and it will print all spans with someclass.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

http://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

I have tried it works good and you can link with django models as well.

You can get many ideas from there , how to take user input